# Angular 4 navigate method doesn't render page contents on the target component (ngIf, ngFor)

Tags: angular

I've a component called nav-bar.component.ts which passes the search query to another component using following method.

nav-bar.component.ts

```
publishSearchQuery(query) {
if (query !== '') {
  this.searchService.publicSearchQuery(query);
  this.router.navigate(['search']);
}
```

The other component OnInit() method contains the call to searchLectures() method

```
searchLectures(url) {
console.log('lectures', this.searchQuery);
if(url === URLS.apiUrl + 'search/notes') {
  this.results = null;
}
this.searchService.searchNotes(url + '?q=' + this.searchQuery ).subscribe(
  results => {
    if (this.results) {

      const temp = this.results.data;
      results.data = temp.concat(results.data);
      this.results = results;
    } else {
      this.results = results;
      console.log(this.results);
    }
  }
);
}
```

The api call is made and I can see the results in the console, but they are not being rendered in the page, 
I searched it and saw this
[issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8012#issuecomment-208940860) and it has something to do with polyfills but I'm not sure.

I tried to solve the issue, but comments are for angular 2, and I'm using angular-cli (webpack)

Comment: can you give us your HTML template?

Comment: `<div *ngIf="results">{{results | json }}</div>`  if I use as simple as this it doesn't render, I also noticed that the ngOnInit is not triggered on first navigation

Comment: When the component is first render it doesn't make the API call, but when I pass it the search query second time, while it's rendered, then the ngOnInit() is called and API call is made

Comment: I'm not sure that I got exactly, but how both components interracts? I mean how first component pass params to second. And where this `<div *ngIf="results">{{results | json }}</div>` template is located? in second component?

Comment: Both the components use a service ( SearchService) which has Observable, the second component (search-results Component ) subscribes to the Observable, get the query string and make the API call

Comment: Every time when you search something you have to navigate? I think it strange behaviour. You said that you have see api calls, and what your console.log shows?

Comment: I've tested everything, and it's working fine, the real problem is when the component is rendered first time, ngOnInit is not called and I also attached the link to the angular issue, many people had the same issue of ngOninit() not being called on navigation, but there workarounds are about the angular 2 configurations and I'm using angular 4 and don't know how to mirror it in webpack config

Comment: Maybe you could just subscribe to observable in second component (in constructor), that emits your search queries, and then call api?

Comment: Already tried it, API call is made, and results are showed in console, but no rendering in page,I found that ngIf and ngFor also not working and it's something to do with lifecycle hooks, maybe they are not triggered on navigation, kindly have a look at the issue I attached

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I kept on struggling to find the real cause of the issue, although I also came across the issue in angular `navigate()` method which I attached with my question.
The real problem was the Observable, I was using `Subject` to emit search query and in the second component I was getting the Observable using `asObservable()` method and then subscribing.
But since I pushed the query value in the first component and then after navigation subscribed in the second component, so the first query value was being wasted ( not emitted on subscription due to the nature of the `Subject`)
So I changed it from `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject` and it worked because `BehaviorSubject` emits the last value.